Pourquoi « vous lire » pour « lire votre réponse » est 'felicitous', mais l'anglais n'accepte 'read you' pour 'read your response' ?

The litteral translation is awaiting the pleasure of reading you; in other words, I look forward to reading your reply. Lire is still a verb, in its infinitive form.


My guess is that it's supposed to be 'Dans l'attente de vous lire', a formula for closing a letter that literally means 'While waiting to read you', but is really equivalent to 'We look forward to hearing from you'.

En anglais, "reading you" dans les citations ci-dessus est "infelicitous",  saugrenu, braque ! Aucun anglophone natif sensé ne terminerait une lettre professionelle
avec "reading you".
Pourquoi le français n'exige-t-il pas « En espérant votre réponse », au lieu de « En espérant vous lire » ?
En d'autres termes, pourquoi « vous » implique-t-il « votre réponse » en français, mais "you" n'implique pas 'your response' en anglais ?

awating the pleasure of reading you sounds Edwardian or Victorian. People used to use things like that...

I did write Release v3.30.5 is now @the://usual.URL, awaiting your gracious attention in an email, once. Just for the fun of it. In my defense, I believed the addressee was English like his employer.


Pourquoi le français n'exige-t-il pas « En espérant votre réponse », au lieu de « En espérant vous lire » ?

Je trouve en espérant vous lire plus courtois. On force moins la main de l'autre personne qu'avec votre réponse qui mentionne explicitement ce qu'on attend. Avec vous lire, on est plus vague.

En d'autres termes, pourquoi « vous » implique-t-il « votre réponse » en français, mais "you" n'implique pas 'your response' en anglais ?

De vous lire est une expression idiomatique, un raccourci pour de lire (quelque chose (qui vient)) de vous. Le propre des expressions idiomatiques est qu'elles ont du mal à être traduite littéralement. Savoir pourquoi you n'implique pas your response est hors-sujet sur FSE mais il semble que looking forward to reading from you, même si la formule consacrée est hearing from you, se rencontre parfois et correspond bien à ce qu'on dit en français.

+1 pour la suggestion reading from you.

"Looking forward to reading from you" doit être rare, presque une forme personnelle ("hearing" est courant): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looking+forward+to+reading+from%2Clooking+forward+to+hearing+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3. Voir aussi ce lien: https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-end-a-letter

@LPH Effectivement, c'est beaucoup plus rare et probablement souvent le fait de non anglophones natifs. Le sens devrait cependant être compris et c'est bien celui attendu.

Pour préciser mon commentaire: sans décider si reading from you est "felicitous" (ce qui est hors-sujet sur fr.SE), la suggestion tape dans le mille sur le fait que reading you ne l'est pas.
